# Covariant derivative and divergence, how are they linked?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, divergence-operator

I have some troubles understanding covariant derivatives in different basis.

Let's start by taking a manifold M with some metric g, then let's set a coordinate basis for the tangent bundle $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, the covariant derivative should be:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu = \partial_\mu V^\nu + \Lambda^\nu_{\mu\rho}V^\rho$$
where $\Lambda$ are Christoffel symbols.
What I don't understand is how to calculate:
$$ div V = \nabla_\mu V^\mu = \ast d\ast (V) $$
where V in the last equation is the one form associated to the vector field V through musical isomorphism.
Taking the above mentioned formula and doing all the calculations I obtain
$$\ast d\ast(V) = \partial_\mu V^\mu$$
but I am missing all the Christoffel symbols. Why?

I have noticed that If I choose a non coordinate basis $e_a$, in particular an orthonormal one, then all Christoffel symbols are 0 and therefore this relation holds:
$$div V = \nabla_a V^a = \partial_a V^a = \ast d\ast(V)$$
but how can I go back to the original coordinate basis to show the same relation in that basis?
I am very confused about this topic, sorry if I wrote something completely wrong.

Thank you

Comment: For starters, you’re neglecting the metric in the musical isomorphism.

Comment: Using the differential forms formula you should easily arrive at the Voss-Weyl formula. Otherwise, it means you didn’t understand the Hodge star. Also, in an orthonormal frame the Christoffel symbols do not necessarily vanish. Also all the metric isomorphisms…

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4426353/568204) for a computation using the Hodge star, and see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4659710/568204) for one using Lie derivatives, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4260519/568204) for a discussion using Christoffel symbols to arrive at the Voss-Weyl formula.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I am doing something wrong with the hodge star operator. In an orthonormal frame Christoffel symbols do not necessarily vanish because the metric is not guaranteed to be constant?

Comment: the metric components in an orthonormal frame are of course constant; they’re $\delta_{ij}$. But, the Lie bracket of these vector fields doesn’t necessarily vanish, and that’s the issue. In a coordinate-induced orthonormal frame, they do commute, so the constancy of metric components coupled with vanishing commutator implies the Christoffel symbols vanish.